# Telerik mvc grid with a dropdownlist in view

Tags: model-view-controller, grid, telerik

I have a dropdownlist with a submit button in my view. When I select a value in dropdownlist and hit submit button, HTTPPOST action in the controller is called and it binds data to the telerik mvc grid. Now, if I click the paging link in the grid, HTTPGET action in the controller is called and the grid is gone. How to persist the selected value of the dropdownlist and rebind data to telerik grid? Appreciate your help

Comment: If it's one value from the combobox, why not make your form action GET instead of post and even make the value part of your route so you can get to the selected sub group with a simple URL?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options

1. Use Ajax binding for your grid. Then the page won't refresh.
2. Pass the required value to the Select method of the databinding settings:

   ```
   <%= Html.Telerik().Grid()
           .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding
              .Server()
              .Select("Action", "Controller", 
                 new { value = ViewData["dropDownValue"] })
           )    
   %>
   ```

Then you can get it from the action method:

```
public ActionResult Action(string value)
{
   //
}
```